# Brew install libxc error

Tags: python, compiler-errors, installation, homebrew

I am trying to install Libxc (library of exchange-correlation functionals for density-functional theory) to be able to use GPAW with ASE. I'm runnig on OSX, and when simply attempting to install libxc with Homebrew, I get the following errors:

```
==> Using Homebrew-provided fortran compiler.
This may be changed by setting the FC environment variable.
==> Downloading http://www.tddft.org/programs/octopus/down.php?file=libxc/libxc-2.0.2.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/libxc-2.0.2.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libxc/2.0.2 --enable-shared FCCPP=cc -E -C -ansi CC=cc CFLAGS=-pipe
==> make
mv -f .deps/libxc_la-mgga_c_vsxc.Tpo .deps/libxc_la-mgga_c_vsxc.Plo
mv -f .deps/libxc_la-mgga_c_pkzb.Tpo .deps/libxc_la-mgga_c_pkzb.Plo
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2

READ THIS: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
```

I have the newest version of gfortran (via Homebrew) and XCODE Command Line Tools installed, which are required to compile.
Homebrew is also up to date and isn't complaining.

Any hints on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!